# basic php 'if then' URL link in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to write code that will display a URL link if there one present from a form sumbmission;

```
If > [a link exists]

then [display the text 'more info' with the href link wrapped around it]
```

I've confused myself mixing wordpress and php, and can't quite get it. Any help would be great.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question more? maybe even add an example ?

Comment: It appears OP would like to automatically create a clickable link if a URL exists in the submitted form.

Answer (score 0):

This question isn't very specific, but the pseudo-code I can offer is this:

```
<?php if (isset($_GET['url'])): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $_GET['url']; ?>">Read more</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to do something like this to the comments displayed on a post?

Comment: "I like https://www.google.com/" becomes "I like [more info](https://www.google.com/)".

If that's the case, perhaps adding a filter to `functions.php` to search for and replace URL might do the trick:

```
// define the get_comment_text callback 
function filter_get_comment_text( $comment_comment_content, $comment, $args ) { 
    // Regular expression to find URL 
    $pattern = '/(https?):\/\/(www\.)?[a-z0-9\.:].*?(?=\s)/i';

    // Replace url with linked "more info"
    $replacement = '<a href="$0">more info</a>';

    // Find matches & replace
    $newcomment = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $comment_comment_content);

    // Return the comment
    return $newcomment;
}; 

// add the filter 
add_filter( 'get_comment_text', 'filter_get_comment_text', 10, 3 );
```